# How to redirect with a variable that's already stored as an array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-4

I have the following code:

```
public function searchgrouppost(){

         $subject1 = Input::get('subject1');
         $subject2 = Input::get('subject2');
         $subject3 = Input::get('subject3');
         $subject4 = Input::get('subject4');
         $subject5 = Input::get('subject5');
         $subject6 = Input::get('subject6');
         $subject7 = Input::get('subject7');

//collects by variables and stores them in an array                              
$subjects = [];
$inputs = Input::all();
array_walk($inputs, function ($v, $k) use (&$subjects) {
  if(starts_with($k, 'subject')) {
    $subjects[$k] = $v;
   }
});
  //counts the number of subjects that are chosen    
 $index = count($subjects);


if  ($index == 1){

 //the code below is wrong because if i click on any 
 //other subject other than subject1 I get an error. 

return Redirect::route('home', array('subject1' => $subject1, 'subject2' =>
 $subject2, 'subject3' => $subject3, 'subject4' => $subject4,
'subject5' => $subject5, 'subject6' => $subject6, 'subject7' => $subject7));  

//if the user chooses two subjects

elseif ($index == 2){
//code below is wrong 
return Redirect::route('hometwo', array('subject1' => $subject1,
'subject2'   => $subject2, 'subject3' => $subject3, 
'subject4' =>  $subject4,'subject5' => $subject5, 'subject6' => $subject6,
 'subject7' => $subject7));  
}
```

I am trying to redirect the user to the appropriate url which I can do but how do I pass the variable so that I can use that value on another page?

I cant pass `$subjects` because it's an array.

My routes code if a user chooses one subject looks like this:

```
Route::get('/home/{subject}', array( 'as' => 'home', 
'uses' => 'GroupSubjectController@home'));
```

Comment: Well....they kinda of already are in an array, `Input::get()` is an array. Anyway, you can pass the variable, even as an array, to the next page. Just do `return redirect()->with([ 'somevar' => $your_var]);` or `session flash`

Comment: @Andrew sorry mate but could you write an example on how I could implement the redirect because im unsure how to implement this

Comment: `return redirect('home')->with('subjects' => $subjects);` that's it, literally. You now have full access to the subjects variable on the next page, in your case `home`.

Comment: I get this error: `Call to undefined function redirect()` is it because im using version 4.2?

Comment: Oh, it's 4.2 damn. I'm using 5.1. Lemme have a look at the docs and I'll get back to you.

Comment: [Here we go](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/responses#redirects). You should be able to do `return Redirect::to('home')->with('subjects', '$subjects');`. You should be also able to pass in more params by using an array. as in `return Redirect::to('home')->with(['subjects' => '$subjects'])`

Comment: please if you don't mind thanks

Comment: Lemme know if it works.

Comment: @Andrew sorry bro but it simply isn't carrying over the value in my url. my url should look like `home/1` at the mo im just seeing `home` and it not redirecting

Comment: Omg, I completely misunderstood the question. I thought you wanted to have access to the array itself on the next page. I see now, you want it in your url. That's easier done than said, surprisingly. Literally all you have to do is make dynamic routes for all the possible values. You already have the default route. All you need to do is attach the `home` part, simply concatenate the values using a loop for every value. Messy, but effective. Start with that see where it goes.

Comment: hmm ok I'll have a go. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Use [session flash](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/session#flash-data), this will put a variable in your session, but only for one request.

Right before you do the redirect, add the following line:

```
\Session::flash('subjects', $subjects);
```

Now, on the new page, you can find the array by using:

```
\Session::get('subjects');
```

Comment: sorry but can you please write an example based on my code because im struggling on how to implement this